# Get file count at remote location during FTP in shell script on linux server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ftp, remote-server

**Requirement** : Need to get file count based on wildcard entry present on remote location(Linux server) and store it in variable for validation purpose

Tried the below code

```
export ExpectedFileCount=$(ftp  -inv $FTPSERVER >> $FTPLOGFILE <<END_SCRIPT
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASSWORD
passive
cd $PATH
ls -ltr ${WILDCARD}*xml| wc -l | sed 's/ *//g'
quit
END_SCRIPT)
```

But the code is storing the code snippet in the variable and and executing the commands every time I call the variable.

Please suggest the changes in the script to execute the script once and store the value in the variable

Comment: You should not use `PATH` as a variable in which to store the remote directory, because it has a special meaning to the shell as the executable search path; call it something else. (I haven't yet checked whether this is the only issue.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work (on Ubuntu, no promises about portability):

```
export ExpectedFileCount=`ftp -in $FTPSERVER << END_SCRIPT | tee -a $FTPLOGFILE | egrep -c '\.xml$'
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASSWORD
passive
cd $REMOTE_PATH
ls -l
quit
END_SCRIPT`
```

Issues:

- `$REMOTE_PATH` used in place of `$PATH` for remote directory (as `$PATH` has a special meaning)
- only a simple `ls -l` is performed inside the ftp session, and the output parsed locally, as it does not support arbitrary shell commands
- I can't see how to capture the output of a command with a heredoc using `$(...)`, but it seems to work with backticks if the closing backtick is after the final delimiter

Comment: 1. Why are we using tee instead of re-directional operator( `>>` )?
2. Why `egrep` instead of wc?